# query count of rows where id is less than a series of values in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, psql

I have a table `etl_control` which stores `latest_id` of `x_data` table everyday. Now I have a requirement to get the number of rows for each day. 
My idea is to run a query to get the count based on a condition `x_data.id <= etl_control.latest_id` for everyday and get the count.

The table structures are as follows.

etl_control:

```
record_date     |   latest_id   |
---------------------------------
2016-11-01      |   55          |
2016-11-02      |   125         |
2016-11-03      |   154         |
2016-11-04      |   190         |
2016-11-05      |   201         |
2016-11-06      |   225         |
2016-11-07      |   287         |
```

x_data:

```
id              |   value       |
---------------------------------
10              |   xyz         |
11              |   xyz         |
21              |   xyz         |
55              |   xyz         |
101             |   xyz         |
108             |   xyz         |
125             |   xyz         |
142             |   xyz         |
154             |   xyz         |
160             |   xyz         |
166             |   xyz         |
178             |   xyz         |
190             |   xyz         |
191             |   xyz         |
```

The end result should have the number of rows in x_data for each day. I tried a number of variations using JOIN, WITH and COUNT(*) OVER. But the biggest hurdle is to iteratively compare x_data.id with etl_control.latest_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sorry folks. Got the answer myself after posting the question.

The query is really simple.

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT e.latest_id
    FROM x_data AS x, etl_control AS e
    WHERE x.id <= e.latest_id)
SELECT latest_id, count(*) FROM data GROUP BY latest_id;
```

This basically creates a temp table with latest_id repeated for each row. The latest_id is always greater than or equal to the id from x_data.

A simple group by on this temp table would give the expected result.